# Incrementing an item when a button is pressed, Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, button, uibutton

I am trying to increment an item in Unity when a button is pressed. I set the item value like so `item = shells;` where shells are another variable that I set earlier in my code. I am doing it in this way so that I can change the item value to something else later on like `item = fossils;`.

The problem is that unless I have it as `shells++;` nothing will happen when I press the button.

current code:

```
public double shells; 

public addItem(){
item = shells; 
item++;
```

this code does not do anything when the addItem method is called.

Code that works

```
public double shells; 

public addItem(){
shells++;
```

If there is a better way of doing this please let me know.

Comment: Can you clarify your question, the `++` represents an increment operator that increments a numeric value.  Are you trying to set objects based on a value that is being incremented?

Comment: Please add a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your code

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that you're dealing with "value types". The code you have in your first example is assigning `item` the value of `shells`. Once you do that, you have two variables - `item` and `shells`. When you increment the `item` value (`item++`), you're **ONLY** incrementing the `item` variable. So now `item` will have a value 1 greater than `shells`.

What you COULD do if you chose, is this:

```
public double shells; 

public addItem()
{
    item = shells; 
    item++;
    shells = item; // here, you're assigning shells the value of item.
}
```

The code itself is kind of pointless, but it demonstrates how you would get a modified value back into the original variable.

[Here's](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/value-types#:%7E:text=C%23%20provides%20the%20following%20built-in%20value%20types%2C%20also,4%20char%20that%20represents%20a%20Unicode%20UTF-16%20character) Microsoft's page describing "value types". It'll be beneficial for you to understand the difference between "value types" and "reference types" going forwards.